# Proving that a triangle is isosceles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

**Question:**

> If in a triangle with $A,B,C$ as the angles and $a,b,c$ as the sides opposite to the respective angles: $$\sin(A-B) = \frac{a}{a+b}\sin A\cos B - \frac{b}{a+b}\sin B\cos A$$ then prove that the triangle is isosceles.

I started by using the identity of $\sin(A-B) = \sin A\cos B - \sin B\cos A$. However, I'm not sure how to proceed on from here. Comparing the coefficients doesn't lead me anywhere. A small hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Use [Law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) to find $$\sin A[\sin(A-B)-\sin A\cos B]+\sin B[\sin(A-B)+\cos A\sin B]=0$$

Use $\sin(A-B)$ formula to reach at $$\cos A=\cos B$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure I follow. I get the first step. Not sure how that implies the second or how the second will imply the final result that I have to prove.

Comment: @Gummybears, please find update

Comment: Yep I got it... I had to do a massive facepalm for my stupidity... Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin(A-B) = \frac{a}{a+b}\sin A\cos B - \frac{b}{a+b}\sin B\cos A$$
$\sin(A-B) = \sin A\cos B - \sin B\cos A$. Then 
$$\sin A\cos B - \sin B\cos A=\frac{a}{a+b}\sin A\cos B - \frac{b}{a+b}\sin B\cos A$$
$$\frac{b}{a+b}\sin A\cos B=\frac{a}{a+b}\sin B\cos A$$
$$b\sin A\cos B=a\sin B\cos A$$
$$\frac b{\sin B}\cos B =\frac a{\sin A}\cos A $$
$$2R\cos B =2R\cos A $$
$$\cos B=\cos A \Rightarrow A=B$$

Comment: Oh crap... Why didn't I think of subtracting?... *facepalm*....